# Laravel view:make issue with child view

Tags: php, layout, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

Apologies if this is remedial.  I am new to Laravel and honestly, my layout game is very weak.  Here's the situation.  I have a master layout in app.blade.php.  That works fine.  I then took out the content portion of the welcome page and threw that in a separate view as welcome.blade.php, which I call from a @yield. Works perfectly.  However, that welcome file is still very long and I'd love to break it out into sections and include separate views for each section.  In a non-Laravel world this would be as simple as

```
<?php include('firstsection.php'); ?>
```

Not so much in Laravel, and after much searching and tinkering I feel as if I'm getting further from the right answer.  What I've done is to break out that first section as firstsection.blade.php, and place that file in the views folder of the resources folder.  I am then trying to call that with

```
<?php echo View::make('view.firstection') ?>
```

This, and several different version of this such as appendend .blade.php to the view name, all give me View Not Found errors. I've looked through a ton of questions here and I guess the answer is just lost on me.  Can anyone offer some advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need here is `@include` directive to include partials of your layout. So in your Blade template you can do:

```
@include('firstsection')
```

to divide master view into smaller views.

You can read more at [Control structures](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#control-structures) - **Including Sub-Views** section

**EDIT**

All views are by default relative to `resources/views` directory by default,

If you have file `resources/views/test.blade.php` to include it you simply use

```
@include('test')
```

and when you have file `resources/views/search/test.blade.php` to include it you should use:

```
@include('search.test')
```

You use here `.` as directory separator

Comment: I read that section several times and originally tried this as an @include but couldn't get it to work.  Perhaps I am overthinking it or was thrown off by the "shared", in that it seemed to imply that I needed to create either a folder within resources\views named shared, and place the view in there, or that "shared" was a different structure entirely from "view".

Comment: Nope.  Same error.  Specifically it is View [view.firstsection] not found. (View: /home/me/web/site/resources/views/welcome.blade.php).  It seems as if I need to create this view either in the controller, or with the View:make function in the template, no?  And I am reluctant to create the view within the controller as there are some that I will pass data to as well.

Comment: Assume you have your `app.blade.php` in `resources/views` folder. You can now create one more file in this directory let's say `test.blade.php` and now in your `app.blade.php` you can include it using `@include('test')`

Comment: THAT!!!  I almost want you to post that as a separate answer along with an explanation of why the 'view.' isn't needed even though it's all over the docs that way.  But as it is I'll mark this is solved and hope that if anyone else stumbles into it they'll read these comments.  Thank you, sir.

Comment: @BlindFish I've updated my answer to make it more clear for anyone